# MySql query for each wordpress multisite

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm attempting a query that pulls information for each site in a Wordpress multisite environment. Here's what I have for reference:

```
SELECT
@optionTable:=CONCAT('p1m8z_', blog_id, '_options') AS optionTable,
(SELECT option_value FROM @optionTable WHERE option_name = 'blogname') AS blogName
FROM p1m8z_blogs
```

Though this code doesn't execute, it illustrates what I'm attempting to accomplish.

I know that I can't use a variable as a table name unless it's in a prepared statement so I tried slapping a prepared statement into the subquery:

```
SELECT
@optionTable = CONCAT('p1m8z_', blog_id, '_options') AS optionTable,
(
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM "SELECT option_value FROM ? WHERE option_name = 'blogname'";
    EXECUTE stmt1 USING @optionTable;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
) AS blogName
FROM p1m8z_blogs
```

That doesn't seem to execute either. Can I even put a prepared statement inside a subquery?

How can I write this statement so that it executes?

Answer (score 0):

Both variables and parameters are treated as if they are string values. You cannot use a variable or a parameter as an identifier (i.e. a table name).

You must just concatenate any table names into the string *before* it is prepared.

```
SELECT CONCAT('p1m8z_', blog_id, '_options') INTO @optionTable
FROM p1m8z_blogs;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT option_value FROM `', @optionTable, 
  '` WHERE option_name = ''blogname''');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

The syntax you showed where you embed the PREPARE/EXECUTE inside another query as if it's a subquery is not valid. Only SELECT can be used inside a subquery.

Comment: Thank you, however this only solves half the battle. `@optionTable` would have to be wrapped in something like `GROUP_CONCAT()` to build a list of table names but how to iterate through them to query the options from each table? Currently I'm looking towards stored procedures to work through it.

Comment: I think MySQL stored procedures are a solution for no problems. I don't use them. I would write a client app to loop over the result.

Comment: lol. I don't have much experience in stored procedures. I do have a lot of experience in client apps, I was trying to be clever and find a SQL only solution to grow my skills. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Stored procedures are customary for users of Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server, but the MySQL implementation is pretty weak in comparison. No debugger, no compiler, no packages.